# How to use jquery Show and hide for this work

Tags: jquery

How to use jquery show and hide for this because. I know javascript I have implemented that.How to do that in jquery.

If I clicked monday,tuesday and wednesday. I am showing the monday and tuesday timing form. Assume If I clicked monday. below monday I want to show the monday from time and to time. like wise for tuesday. how to use jquery for this. what property I Have to use and how to use.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function show(element) {
                var day = element.value; // gets the value of checkbox, e.g: 'monday'
                var timeElement = document.querySelector('.times-' + day); // finds correct times- element for day

                if (element.checked) {
                    timeElement.style.display = 'block';  
                } else {
                    timeElement.style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .hidden {
                display: none;
            }

            input[type=submit] {
                margin-top: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form  name="test" action="" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Day And Time Available:</legend>  
                <input type="checkbox" class="day" value="monday" onclick="show(this);"/>Monday<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" class="day" value="tuesday" onclick="show(this);"/>Tuesday<br/>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="times-monday hidden">
                <p>Monday</p>
                <label for="FromtimeMonday">From Time</label>
                <select name="FromtimeMonday" id="FromtimeMonday">
                    <option value="6Am">6Am</option>
                    <option value="7Am">7Am</option>
                    <option value="8Am">8Am</option>
                </select>
                <label for="TotimeMonday">To Time</label>
                <select name="TotimeMonday" id="TotimeMonday">
                    <option value="6Am">6Am</option>
                    <option value="7Am">7Am</option>
                    <option value="8Am">8Am</option>
                </select>  
            </div>

            <div class="times-tuesday hidden">
                <p>Tuesday</p>
                <label for="FromtimeTueday">From Time</label>
                <select name="FromtimeTueday" id="FromtimeTueday">
                    <option value="6Am">6Am</option>
                    <option value="7Am">7Am</option>
                    <option value="8Am">8Am</option>
                </select>

                <label for="TotimeTueday">To Time</label>
                <select name="TotimeTueday" id="TotimeTueday">
                    <option value="6Am">6Am</option>
                    <option value="7Am">7Am</option>
                    <option value="8Am">8Am</option>
                </select>  
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" text="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would use classes e.g. "invisible" and "visible" , and add CSS to hide or show elements with those classes. Use the jQuery to add or remove the classes from the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **[jQuery: is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library.](http://jquery.com/)**

**He makes coffee:**

- You can bind an event like 'click' on a specific element by a selector (example: your input radio with class '.day')
- Instead of using css class for hiding elements, you can use the function [jQuery hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.times-tuesday').toggle();
    $('.times-monday').toggle();
    $(document).on('click', '.day', function() {
        $('.times-' + this.value).toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
    <form name="test" action="" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Day And Time Available:</legend>
            <input type="checkbox" class="day" value="monday"/>Monday
            <br/>
            <div class="times-monday hidden">
                <p>Monday</p>
                <label for="FromtimeMonday">From Time</label>
                <select name="FromtimeMonday" id="FromtimeMonday">
                    <option value="6Am">6Am</option>
                    <option value="7Am">7Am</option>
                    <option value="8Am">8Am</option>
                </select>
                <label for="TotimeMonday">To Time</label>
                <select name="TotimeMonday" id="TotimeMonday">
                    <option value="6Am">6Am</option>
                    <option value="7Am">7Am</option>
                    <option value="8Am">8Am</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="day" value="tuesday"/>Tuesday
            <br/>
            <div class="times-tuesday hidden">
                <p>Tuesday</p>
                <label for="FromtimeTueday">From Time</label>
                <select name="FromtimeTueday" id="FromtimeTueday">
                    <option value="6Am">6Am</option>
                    <option value="7Am">7Am</option>
                    <option value="8Am">8Am</option>
                </select>
                <label for="TotimeTueday">To Time</label>
                <select name="TotimeTueday" id="TotimeTueday">
                    <option value="6Am">6Am</option>
                    <option value="7Am">7Am</option>
                    <option value="8Am">8Am</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" text="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(timeElement).show();

$(timeElement).hide();
```

Comment: can you expand your answer little bit more $(document).ready(function(){
 where to wirte this in  jquery document.querySelector('.times-' + day) $(timeElement).show() el,se $(timeElement).hide(). if possible add in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
$(selector).show();
$(selector).hide();
```

where `selector` can be multiple things, for example a class: `".class"`
or an id: `"#id"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this `.` represents class and `#` represents id you can use in element [**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6dyzvdd3/6/)

```
 $('.day').click(function(){
    var dayname= $(this).attr('id');
    if($('#'+dayname).is(":checked"))      {
    $('#'+dayname+'show').show();  
    }else{
        $('#'+dayname+'show').hide();  
    }

});
```

Comment: <fieldset>
                <legend>Day And Time Available:</legend>  
                <input type="checkbox" class="day" value="monday" onclick="show(this);"/>Monday<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" class="day" value="tuesday" onclick="show(this);"/>Tuesday<br/>
            </fieldset>

Comment: Thanks for  your timing assume If i select monday I need to show monday timing .if I select both monday and tuesday i need to show both monday timing and tuesday form. like wise I have create monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday for all seven in a week. I have given here only monday and tuesday .what i did i javascript.

Comment: see this  function show(element) {
                var day = element.value; // gets the value of checkbox, e.g: 'monday'
                var timeElement = document.querySelector('.times-' + day); // finds correct times- element for day
    alert(timeElement);

                if ($('day').is(":checked")) {
                   $('FromtimeMonday').show();  
                } else {
                   $('day').hide();
                }
            }  it is not coming for me.  event alert is not coming

Comment: who do we bring the show form under if monday is clicked because when i embbed in myform it contains space so if show below monday the work is fine

Comment: yes how to bring .shall we remove the div in html form

Comment: you agree with above answer know please ask him @mathewjohn

Answer (score 0):

I hope this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgoj697s/4/) helps you.

I replaced your funtion with the [JQuery-.click-Funktion](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and deleted

```
 onclick="show(this);"
```

from your checkboxes.

EDIT: I used the [toggle-funktion](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to show/hide your forms.
The whole JQuery-code looks like this, now:

```
$( ".day" ).click(function() {
    $('.times-' + this.value).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Yes you are correct .I want to bring the  form  below monday if monday is clicked. like wise for tuesday .because when i embed in my layout out it is giving space